# Are there any Football Web Services which can be consumed?

Tags: c#, wcf, asmx

I am trying to find a WebService that provides access to current football statistics for Serie A (Italian League) for example and maybe some livescores.

Has someone found any webservice that can be consumed to gather this data, or I need to scrape them from a web page to get them.

For example livescores.com has live scores on its webpage...

I am trying to find a service that can be consumed so I can use it for an app. (I already tried google. So don't tell me to google it)

Comment: Please read [faq] and [ask], please..